# get links while do web scraping to google in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to get links of google while do a search, that is, all these links:.

[image]

I have done this kind of scraping but in this case I do not understand why It doesn't work, so I run the following lines:

```
library(rvest)
url<-"https://www.google.es/search?q=Ediciones+Peña+sl+telefono"
content_request<-read_html(url)
content_request %>%
    html_nodes(".r") %>%
    html_attr("href")
```

I have tried with other nodes and I obtain similar answers:

```
content_request %>%
    html_nodes(".LC20lb") %>%
    html_attr("href")
```

Finally I tried to get all the links of the web page, but there are some links that I cannot download:

```
html_attr(html_nodes(content_request, "a"), "href")
```

Please, could you help me in this case? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options for you to play around with.

```
#1) 

url <- "https://www.google.es/search?q=Ediciones+Pe%C3%B1a+sl+telefono"
html <- paste(readLines(url), collapse="\n")
library(stringr)
matched <- str_match_all(html, "<a href=\"(.*?)\"")


#2) 

library(xml2)
library(rvest)
URL <- "https://www.google.es/search?q=Ediciones+Pe%C3%B1a+sl+telefono"
pg <- read_html(URL)
head(html_attr(html_nodes(pg, "a"), "href"))
```

Comment: In the first case you obtain more links than the showed and in the second one you obtain less links than the showed.